# With get() call a function from an unloaded package without using library

Tags: r, eval

I want to call a function from an unloaded package by having the function name stored in a list.

Normally I would just use:

```
library(shiny)

pagelist <- list("type" = "p") # object with the function name (will be loaded from .txt file)
get(pagelist$type[1])("Display this text")
```

but since when writing a package you're not allowed to load the library I'd have to use something like

```
get(shiny::pagelist$type[1])("Display this text")
```

which doesn't work. Is there a way to call the function from the function name stored in the list, without having to load the library? Note that it should be possible to call many different functions like this (all from the same package), so just using e.g.

```
if (pagelist$type[1] == "p"){
  shiny::p("Display this text")
 }
```

would require a quite long list of if else statemens.

Comment: I deleted my answer `"::"("shiny","p")("Display this text")` because as @Nicola mentioned, it doesn't work with `"::"("shiny",pagelist$type[1])("Display this text")` . If you look at the code of `::` you'll see it's basically a wrapper for `getExportedValue`, except `getExportedValue` can take strings as inputs

Comment: you might be going about this the wrong way.  You're indeed not allowed to use `library()` within package code (although if you don't intend to submit to CRAN you can do whatever you want), but there's an entire set of machinery (see the `Writing R Extensions` manual) for importing functions. Why not store a list of functions imported from `shiny` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `getExportedValue`:

```
getExportedValue("shiny",pagelist$type[1])("Display this text")
#<p>Display this text</p>
```

Comment: A very late comment (this question was just referenced as the original of a dup):  `getExportedValue` is documented as being for internal use.  The public way to do this is `get(pagelist$type[1], loadNamespace("shiny"))("Display this text")`.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use `getExportedValue` as was done in the accepted answer, because its help page describes the functions there as "Internal functions to support reflection on namespace objects."  It's bad practice to use internal functions, because they can change in subtle ways with very little notice.

The right way to do the equivalent of `shiny::p` when both `"shiny"` and `"p"` are character strings in variables is to use `get`:

```
get("p", envir = loadNamespace("shiny"))
```

The `loadNamespace` function returns the exported environment of the package; it's fairly quick to execute if the package is already loaded.

The original question asked

> Is there a way to call the function from the function name stored in
>   the list, without having to load the library?

(where I think "library" should be "package" in R jargon).   The answer to this is "no", you can't get any object from a package unless you load the package.  However, loading is simpler than attaching, so this won't put `shiny` on the search list (making all of `shiny` visible to the user), it's just loaded internally in R.

A related question is why `get("shiny::p")` doesn't work.  The answer is that `shiny::p` is an expression to evaluate, and `get` only works on names.