# Using get() to call a function from a package without loading the package

Tags: r, eval

I want to call a function (`hamming`) where its name is stored as a string. To do this, I used `get`.

```r
# Assign function name to variable
w <- "hamming"

# Load library for 'hamming' function
library(signal)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'signal'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, poly

# Call function using 'get'
get(w)(10)
#>  [1] 0.0800000 0.1876196 0.4601218 0.7700000 0.9722586 0.9722586 0.7700000
#>  [8] 0.4601218 0.1876196 0.0800000
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

That works great.

Now, say I want to do exactly the same thing – and achieve the same result – but without calling `library()`. To do this, I included the package name along with the function name in the string, as follows:

```r
# Assign function name to variable
w <- "signal::hamming"

# Call function using 'get'
get(w)(10)
#> Error in get(w): object 'signal::hamming' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This, however, doesn't work. Why? And how *should* I achieve this result without loading the entire package?

Comment: Since the package isn't loaded `'signal::hamming'` doesn't exist in the environment, so there is nothing to "get". Why not just call `signal::hamming(10))` directly? No need to load the package provided it exists. Or is there perhaps a particular reason why it needs to be stored as a string in another variable?

Comment: Maybe via **evil** parse: `n = 10; eval(parse(text = paste0("signal::hamming(", n, ")")))` Note: `"106. If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question. - Thomas Lumley"`

Comment: @edsandorf I'm not sure I follow your logic. I understand that the package isn't loaded – that's why I use a package preface (i.e., `signal::`) to access the function. It works when I use `signal::hamming(10)` directly *without* the package loaded, so why not when I use `get`? What's the fundamental difference? The function name will be provided as a string, which is why I can't simply  use `signal::hamming(10)`.

Comment: `get` only searches in the defined environment, if package is not loaded, it is not in any environment. What is the real use case for this, why are we doing this?

Comment: @zx8754 I think your solution can be condensed to `eval(parse(text = w))(10)`. The user is providing the function name as a string to a function that lives in a package. Since that function lives in a package, it's using `::` to access functions from other packages.

Comment: The answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45302215/with-get-call-a-function-from-an-unloaded-package-without-using-library uses a function marked as being for internal use.  The proper way to do this is `get("hamming", envir = loadNamespace("signal"))(10)`.

Comment: @user2554330 That's the solution. Can we reopen and post this as an answer?

Comment: Sure.  I've voted to re-open.  Not sure how many other re-open votes it will need...

Comment: Since this question hasn't been re-opened, I've now added a new answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45302215/with-get-call-a-function-from-an-unloaded-package-without-using-library.  Hopefully it answers your question as well.